# How to check if a variable is set then include one thing, if not, include another in template in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have the following iframe in my template:

```
<iframe [src]="localState.url? localState.url : 'http://www.google.com' | safety"></iframe>
```

safety is a pipe to clean up any unsafe urls. The issue have is the above doesnt work. If I just did:

```
<iframe [src]="localState.url | safety"></iframe>
```

It does. How can I correctly use the conditional in my first snippet?

Comment: Have you tried `<iframe [src]="localState.url | safety ? localState.url | safety : 'http://www.google.com' | safety"></iframe>`?

Comment: Giving me a syntax error when I put pipe safety in front of that first variable. It actually doesnt like my conditional at all.

Comment: Ah sorry it shouldn't be on the first one. And ParthaSarathiGhosh's answer seems to be correct too.

Comment: If you don't come right you could always just put the conditional in your component class: `this.url = localState.url? localState.url : 'http://www.google.com'` and then use the local variable in your template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
<iframe 
  [src]="(localState.url? localState.url : 'http://www.google.com') | safety">  
</iframe>
```

Here I just put two bracket ( and )